# Kubernetes - API Server SSL

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set up a k8s cluster with couple of ubuntu instances on AWS.

I have successfully installed

- docker
- kubelet
- kubeadm
- kubectl etc

The machines IPs are like this. They are all the in same network. Firewall is fully enabled. I am able to telnet port 6443 etc.

IP and Hostnames

```
10.0.0.100 (ip-10-0-0-100.ca-central-1.compute.internal)
10.0.0.101 (ip-10-0-0-101.ca-central-1.compute.internal)
10.0.0.102 (ip-10-0-0-102.ca-central-1.compute.internal)
```

**10.0.0.100**:

I ran this command

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.0.0.100 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

It issued a token with join command.

**10.0.0.101:**

I ran the command join command on 10.0.0.101 and It got timed out. (Fresh Token & not yet expired)

```
Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get "https://10.0.0.100:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**10.0.0.100:**

So i was trying to access on the master node. The api-server was not even accessible on same node. even via localhost:6443 does not work.

```
curl https://10.0.0.100:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info
```

Getting below error.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Interestingly this works.

```
curl -k https://10.0.0.100:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info
```

What could be the reason?

---

nslookup ip shows something like this.

```
nslookup 10.0.0.101
101.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa name = ip-10-0-0-101.ca-central-1.compute.internal.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: when you try to access apiserver directly using curl we need to pass cacert,cert& key so please try this command on master ndde ```sudo curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key https://10.0.0.100:6443/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info```

Comment: regarding the cluster join command failure , it looks dns look up issues . please add ```cat /etc/hosts``` and ```hostname -f``` output to the question

Comment: @confusedgenius, ip-10-0-0-100.ca-central-1.compute.internal - this is the master

Comment: can you add the outputs to the question itself so that formatting will be easier to read

Comment: @confusedgenius updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we need to verify two things :

1. whether apiserver is functional or not using curl from master node :

```sh
sudo curl --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key https://10.0.0.100:6443/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info
```

2. whether name resolution is working fine among the nodes :

- following commands need to be ran on all nodes to verify  :

```sh
nslookup 10.0.0.101 
nslookup 10.0.0.100
nslookup 10.0.0.102
```

- if the nslookup is resolving those ip addresses then you need to add following entries in `/etc/hosts` file on all nodes :

```
10.0.0.100 ip-10-0-0-100.ca-central-1.compute.internal
10.0.0.101 ip-10-0-0-101.ca-central-1.compute.internal
10.0.0.102 ip-10-0-0-102.ca-central-1.compute.internal
```

- after updating /etc/hosts file , re-verify using nslookup commands :

```sh
nslookup 10.0.0.101 
nslookup 10.0.0.100
nslookup 10.0.0.102
```

- try to re-add the node using join command